# How to retrieve data from referenced table in Hibernate

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

I am working on `Hibernate` with `Mysql` Where i have three tables namely

- Personaldetails
- Employeedetails
- Masterrecord

Here i

- `Employeedetails is referenced from Personaldetails` and `Masterrecord is referenced from Employeedetails`
- But **note that** `Masterrecord is not directly link from Personaldetails`

I have attached the structure format below

[image]

**My Question is:**

I need to access the **Master record record from Personal details**

for this following query is not working

```
select a.fname,a.employeedetails.empId,a.employeedetails.masterrecord.deptCode from pojo.Personaldetails as a
```

I have tried this in Eclipse HQL editor,Its not working it's returning as follows

[image]
Shall i have any other suggestion for this...

Comment: Can you please tell me you need all the fields in those three table

Comment: Ya for this case i don't need, but for some purpose i need,

Comment: Please check the multiple join query...

Comment: It will be easier if you plot it with some query , for my above query requirement

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT m.* From Masterrecord AS m
         LEFT JOIN  Employeedetails AS e ON e.DeotCode = m.DeotCode 
         LEFT JOIN  Personaldetails AS p ON p.Refld = e.Refld
          GROUP BY p.Refld
```

This only get the Masterrecord table values.if u need same where condition

```
SELECT m.* From Masterrecord AS m
             LEFT JOIN  Employeedetails AS e ON e.DeotCode = m.DeotCode 
             LEFT JOIN  Personaldetails AS p ON p.Refld = e.Refld WHERE p.Refld = 101
              GROUP BY p.Refld
```